# Objective-C, Displaying an NSTimer activated by a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, nstimer, countdowntimer

I'm working on a project for school that includes a set of buttons that create NStimers used as a countdown timer. Ideally, the time would display as the title of the UIButton that started the timer.

So far I have only been able make this work if when setting the display of the time I refer to a specific instance of a UIButton rather than a somehow passing a UIButton argument. 
I also have declared "time" NSString that holds the current displayed value calculated by the NSTimer. This is not how the final implementation should be, and I only have it set up like this just to have it partially working.

Code for one of the buttons:

```
b1 = [[UIButton alloc]
             initWithFrame:CGRectMake(neutral.frame.size.width * 0.56, neutral.frame.size.height * 0.18, neutral.frame.size.height * 0.64, neutral.frame.size.height * 0.64)];
    [b1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:35.0]];
    [b1 setBackgroundImage: forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Method called from button press action:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{ 
    //do stuff


timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:t] repeats:YES];  }
```

NSTimer timer fired method:

```
-(void)timerFired
{    
if((curMin>0 || curSec>=0) && curMin>=0)
{
    if(curSec==0)
    {
        curMin-=1;
        curSec=59;
    }
    else if(curSec>0)
    {
        curSec-=1;
    }
    if(curMin>-1)
    {
    time = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d%@%02d",curMin,@":",curSec];
    [b1 setTitle:time forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
else
{

    [b1 setTitle: nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [timer invalidate];

   }
}
```

I hope that was clear enough as to what I am trying to accomplish. I am somewhat surprised that I haven't been able to find anything to walk me through this. I am flexible to changing how exactly this works. All that really matters is that each button can start a unique countdown timer.

I'm sure that this code is sloppy, but Objective C is relatively new to me so any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store *time* as minutes/seconds, just use seconds, as all that *greater than 60* logic is really tedious isn't it.

I've chosen to call the instance variable `_secondsLeft` so I will know what it means when I look at the code in 6 months time:

```
-(void)timerFired
{    
    NSString *formatted = @"";
    if (secondsLeft > 0)
    {
        secondsLeft--;
        formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (secondsLeft / 60), (secondsLeft % 60)];
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    [b1 setTitle:formatted forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```